# Calling Host Method from Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I want to call method that resides on the host executable that I am using to execute a workflow with WorkflowInvoker.Invoke.

I have found examples of this via an interface using [ExternalDataExchange], but all of these are examples are for Workflow 3.5, nothing for 4 or 4.5. It also appears that the ExternalDataExchange has been deprecated on 4+.

Does anyone have an example of doing this in WF 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Your host needs to register extensions by doing something like:

```
yourWFApp.Extensions.Add<ISomeInterface>(
    () => { return AnObjectThatImplmentsISomeInterface;});
```

Then, your activities can use that extension by doing:

```
ISomeInterface hostInterface = activityContext.GetExtension<ISomeInterface>();
hostInterface.CallTheHost();
```

Comment: Funny thing is I just finally found the answer to this and saw that I got a reply to my question. Thank you for taking the time to answer though.